# Navigation Menu swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, menu, swrevealviewcontroller

i created Menu using **SWRevealViewController** it connected to whole application but when i choose any row from menu in any view it go to home page first.
any one know the why and how to solve this problem.

the couse of the problem is that i use             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
)}

[image]

menu code

```
extension UIViewController {
func addMenu() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"menu")!

    if (varView == 0) {

    }
    else if (varView == 1) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

             let update = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("updateuser") as! UpdateUserProfileViewController          

              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(update, animated: false)
      )}
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: @Amal EL-galant please check for multiple segue connections.

Comment: i want multiple to support English and Arabic language

Comment: @AmalEl-galant when you select a row can you check how many segue connection you have?? Means segue to which all controllers you have,

Comment: problem is not in segue i already do that the cause of my problem using this line and i should use it         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

Comment: @AmalEl-galant why using dispatch queue for segue?

Comment: not for segue segue only to convert langue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making menu static (created 8 cells for all menu rows), and then made segue from each one.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do something related to UI you have to be in Main Queue. Your code should be like below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
       let update = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("updateuser") as! UpdateUserProfileViewController          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(update, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async  in swift 3 i use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ for swift 2.2 and this line the cause of the problem because when i remove it app works good

Comment: @AmalEl-galant so your problem is solved? its because of main queue ?

Comment: i cant remove this line as i need it dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

Comment: @AmalEl-galant - can you show the SWL didselect row

Comment: @AmalEl-galant - problem not in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),`

Comment: actually i have 7 conditions i use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), for 5 of them where problem happen and when i tried to add this line to other condition the same problem happened for them

Comment: in menu table view controller 
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: 
    AnyObject?) {
            var indexPath : NSIndexPath = 
    self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            varView = indexPath.row
        
        }